# Teradata SQL Assistant - auto export

Tags: teradata

Just wonder if anyone had similar question. So, can you somehow create a scrip in Teradata SQL Assistant to automatically export query results?

Comment: If you select `export results` from the file menu, it exports every query you run until you de-select it.

Comment: If you want to export using SQL Assistant on command line there are startup parameters: https://docs.teradata.com/reader/HH8~IyFfLq4okp1pES~6cA/GTY2MbQJZB8zV9WJ3M2OHg